# libgdx: AssetsManager error

Tags: java, android, load, libgdx

I looking for the `AssetManager` class on `libgdx` and when I try to load files with the `load()` method, desktop project works but the android project doesn't works.

This is the error:

```
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1008
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488): com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load dependencies of asset: data/0.png

12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488): at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.handleTaskError(AssetManager.java:517)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:351)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at fr.orandjadev.utils.RessourcesManager.update(RessourcesManager.java:30)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at fr.orandjadev.samourai.Game.render(Game.java:36)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:499)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1462)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1216)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load dependencies of asset: data/0.png

12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:119)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.update(AssetLoadingTask.java:89)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.updateTask(AssetManager.java:454)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:349)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    ... 5 more
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/0.png

12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncResult.get(AsyncResult.java:46)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:117)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    ... 8 more
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/0.png

12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.TextureLoader.loadAsync(TextureLoader.java:72)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.TextureLoader.loadAsync(TextureLoader.java:41)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:69)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:34)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncExecutor$2.call(AsyncExecutor.java:65)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: data/0.png
 (Internal)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:74)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:217)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    ... 10 more
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data/0.png

12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:406)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:380)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:72)
12-26 23:15:23.243: E/AndroidRuntime(15488):    ... 12 more
```

I set a ressource like that.

```
public void loadTexture(String path){
    assetmanager.load(path, Texture.class);
}
```

and the path is like `data/0.png`.

Previously on my code I use `Gdx.files.internal(somepaths);` and it works perfectly... 
I think I don't understand something. the desktop project is linked to the assets folder of android project.

Comment: Is any one of the characters in the actual path to the resource in different case than the one defined in the "path" string you supply to the `loadTexture()`? For example, file system path is "data/0.PNG" and in your application you specify "data/0.png"? In this situation it will work on desktop and not on android. Also, if you haven't done so, try refreshing your android assets folder and cleaning the projects before running,

Answer (score 1):

When you keep a file in the assets folder, you must always use Gdx.files.internal(path)

The reason that it works on desktop and not on android is that file systems are implemented differently on all platforms. So the best choice is to use platform independent api given by libgdx itself in stead of directly giving the path.

There are File path resolvers under the hood to take care of platform idiosyncrasies.
For more, refer https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/FileHandling

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In general: You should the AssetManager instead of accessing the files via Gdx.files.internal() because the AssetManager does not create platform dependant code. Usually on the desktop assets are placed in the bin folder, for Android, bin is missing in the path. The AssetManager cares about that stuff internally.

The problem you faced with the AssetManager is an asynchronous problem. The line

```
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.handleTaskError(AssetManager.java:517)
```

in the output gives a little hint on that. AssetManager.load() loads its stuff asynchronous, means it creates a separate task to laod stuff. Hence make sure to call finishLoading(), before you use stuff loaded by the AssetManager. This method waits until everything is loaded.

This should work:

```
public void loadTexture(String path){
    assetmanager.load(path, Texture.class);
    assetmanager.finishLoading();
}
```